# discord.js/node : filter().map() best method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning javascript with discord.js and node and I'm always looking for the "best" code.

Is this the "best code" for my map() ? ([role] required, (role) optional)

```
// Get [role] (@role) args
let roles = msg.mentions.roles.filter(role => (args[2] === `<@&${role.id}>` || args[3] === `<@&${role.id}>`)).map(role => {
  nbArgs++;
  return role.id;
});

// Get text
let txtContent = msg.content.split(/ +/g).splice(nbArgs).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is better :

```
let roles = msg.mentions.roles.filter(role => (args[2] === role.toString() || args[3] === role.toString())).map(role => role.id);
```

And use `roles.length instead` of `nbArgs++` :

```
// Get text
let txtContent = msg.content.split(/ +/g).splice(roles.length + nbArgs).join(' ');
```